# Question when deriving quantum differential privacy?

Tags: mathematics, machine-learning

I met some problems when trying to derive **proposition 4** in the paper [Gentle measurement of quantum states and differential privacy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08747.pdf).

I know that intuitively, if we act on a single register of ρ, and then measure in the
computational basis , we map each database X to a distribution over neighbors
X ′ of X. But I can't write it down in a strict mathematical way. So what is the detailed version of this statement?